# Windows 10 1809 screen turns off after 5 minutes regardless of power settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

- Windows 10 1809
- Desktop computer

Settings > Power & sleep > Screen > When plugged in, turn off after > 15 minutes
[image]

Control Panel > Power options > Edit Plan Settings > Turn off the display > 15 minutes
[image]

Control Panel > Power options > Edit Plan Settings > Change advanced power setting > Display > Turn off display after > 15 minutes

[image]

Despite all these settings set to turn off the screen after 15 minutes my screen turns off after 5 minutes.

Where else is there to change screen time out settings to have the screen turn off after user desired interval?

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS power settings?

Comment: I don't think there is a setting in BIOS to turn off the screen but I'll check next time I reboot and report back...

Comment: My screen saver was set to none and Wait was set to 5 minutes so it was actually screen saver that was kicking in. The same effect would be if the screen saver was set to "Blank".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My screen saver was set to none and Wait was set to 5 minutes so it was actually screen saver that was kicking in. The same effect would be if the screen saver was set to "Blank".

Comment: Oh, yup. That's caught many of us. You should be able to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: The led on this Acer monitor is on the bottom for some reason, so I didn't notice the monitor is on... Have to wait another 11 hours to mark as answer.

Comment: "(None)" screen saver is supposed to not be a screen saver, it is supposed to disable the screen saver. This is why the "Wait: X minutes" time option is deselected. Seems to be a bug in Windows.

Answer (score 6):

When untouched, the Windows 10 Lock Screen times out and switches off your screen after one minute. This can be adjusted via the registry:

1. Open the Registry Editor by searching for Regedit in the start menu or search bar
2. Navigate to the following path with the bar on the side: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7
3. Double left-click the Attributes value to open the Properties window in the right hand-pane
4. Change the value in the Value data box from 1 to 2, then click OK
5. Go to Power Options in the Control Panel and click change plan settings
6. Click on Change Advanced Power Options
7. Expand the Display item and choose Console lock display off timeout

Comment: Thank you, this has been really annoying me!  On another laptop I made it go away by creating a new power profile but that didn't work this time and I was stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this kind of issue.  [This solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/prevent-windows-10-screen-display-from-turning-off/1b9dd406-3b6c-45a1-ae9a-3da283899eab) fixed it:

In your "Power & sleep" settings, set your screen to *never* turn off if it's plugged in.

[image]

More information on my situation:

- I would lock my computer to go to the bathroom, come back in 3-5 minutes and see my screen turned off.
- Setting my screen-saver to kick in after 9999 minutes (as suggested by another answer here) didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise to open the Windows Power Options and modify any other power plans that may be becoming active. The sleep settings are specific to each power plan, so if it is being switched on idle or otherwise, then the sleep settings would be adopted from the other power plan.

Comment: By default, Windows Power Options does not switch from one power plan to another. If using an application such as "Power Plan Switcher", you might need to follow those steps. But you should not need to do this otherwise. Just set the plan you are on.