# Windows 10 turns off the display after 15 minutes regardless of Power Settings

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, power-options

**Problem: Precisely 15 minutes after laptop has been idle, the display turns off/goes black**

- Laptop DELL Inspiron 5490
- Windows 10 Home
- Connected to 2 monitors (1x HDMI 1 Type-C)
- Plugged in to power
- Power Options (Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options) don't take effect, whatever value I put there (5 min, 10 min, 2 hours or Never) display will always turn off after 15 min idle
- Screensaver switched off (none) and Wait greyed out
- Sleep unattended sleep timeout unhidden but does nothing
- Monitor screens Sleep mode switched off
- Downloaded a freeware app called Don't Sleep 7.77 - but it also didn't prevent

**I wonder if the laptop (DELL) has inbuilt sleep settings that override Windows 10 as it does not follow any power settings selected.**

I have checked these threads below but none of them provided a solution for my issue:

- [Windows 10 goes to sleep ignoring the settings](https://superuser.com/questions/984881/windows-10-goes-to-sleep-ignoring-the-settings)
- [Windows 10 Sleeps Before Set Time](https://superuser.com/questions/1019043/windows-10-sleeps-before-set-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Windows 10 1809 screen turns off after 5 minutes regardless of power settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1398863/windows-10-1809-screen-turns-off-after-5-minutes-regardless-of-power-settings)

[image: 1]

Thank you

Comment: Are you setting the power settings as an admin or non-admin user.  I've found that sleep settings are completely ignored for non-admin users.

Comment: Are these identical monitors?